# iPhone map pin circle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

i am new to Xcode. any tips on how to make this image http://www.google.com/gmm/images/blue_dot_circle.png in the map? something like GPS kind . 
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to show this circle image on user's current location ? Please describe what exactly you want and where ?

Comment: I've got the current user location. I'm trying to draw the circle around the current user location. Also I'm using route-me api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can draw a circle with a radius based on gps accuracy.

for example:

```
- (id) init {
    shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shape];
}

- void updateCircle() {
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    float ix = -radius_ + self.frame.size.width  / 2;
    float iy = -radius_ + self.frame.size.height / 2;

    CGRect ellipseRect = CGRectMake(ix, iy, radius_ * 2 , radius_ * 2 );
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, ellipseRect);

    // draw circle
    shape.strokeColor = [[borderColor_ colorWithAlphaComponent:borderOpacity_] CGColor];
    shape.fillColor = [[color_ colorWithAlphaComponent:opacity_] CGColor];
    shape.lineWidth = borderWidth_;
    shape.path = path;
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

after that, you can add your circle in your subview.

This snippet draw a cirlce with a border. Useful for gps accuracy.

You should view this circle (without the red circle, that is a Mkpin...):
[image]

hope this helps.

Comment: how do you declare the shape object?

Comment: ops, sorry. see edit. shape is `CAShapeLayer` declared in init.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
 [circle setTitle:@"insideFill"];
 [mapView addOverlay:circle];

MKCircle *circleLine = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:location radius:radius];
[circleLine setTitle:@"outsideCircle"];
[mapView addOverlay:circleLine];
```

and

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay{
MKCircle *circle = overlay;
MKCircleView *circleView = [[[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay] autorelease];

if ([circle.title isEqualToString:@"insideFill"])
{
    circleView.fillColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x598DD3);
    circleView.alpha = 0.25;
}
else
{
    circleView.strokeColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x5C8AC7);
    circleView.lineWidth = 2.0;
}


 return circleView;
```

}

and

```
  #define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) \
         [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
                         green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
                         blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 \
                         alpha:1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty difficult to trace a route to your destination without knowing where you stand.

First off, you should read this [`guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1) and then [`google for tutorials`](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=Mapkit+tutorial). One of many is [`this`](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/).

You will have to concern yourself about [`overlays`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [`overlay views`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I'm using a route-me api.I've got the user's current location but I want to draw the circle image around the user's current location.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for that you don't need to draw circle image. It would be draw automatically. Just use below code and it will have circle on user's current location.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;

    if(annotation !=mapView.userLocation){
        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *) 
        [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"identifier"]; 
        if(nil == view) { 
            view = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"] 
                    autorelease];           
        }
        [view setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorPurple];
        view.enabled = YES;
        view.canShowCallout = YES;
        view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        view.animatesDrop = YES;
    }       
    return view;
}
```

You Just need to return nil view if it is user's current location. So it will draw circle with dot automatically.

Let me know if this help and if you have any question in above code. 
Note: comment which lines are not necessary for you.

Comment: I haven't use route-me api so I am not sure about that but may be you can take a try once ?